# UIView Rotation Magically Happening

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, uiview

I was given a project that was started by someone else who no longer works here.
I have a UITabBarController which holds some UIViewControllers.
If the application is running on iOS 6, everything runs fine, However as soon as I run it on iOS 5, all UIViews are rotated 90 degrees and given an origin value of something around -100 to -300

I have been able to loop through all view controllers of the tabBar and set

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,748);
```

The initial view controllers on UITabBarController appear correctly, However, if I ever try to launch a modal view controller, everything is stuffed again. including the modal.

I am running out of ideas on how I could fix this once and for all. I couldn't find anything in the code that rotates the views.

What I could deduce is
on iOS 6, the first subview of the main view holding the UITabBarController is UILayoutContainerView
but on iOS 5 the first subview is of class UIView

If this is an issue with UILayoutContainerView not being supported in iOS5, how can I make the application backwards compatible now?

**Note:** we only support Landscape (Right/Left) and only on iPad.
Also, I have noticed that if the user rotates the application before initialiazing the UITabBarController and its sub controllers. everything works fine. Even if you re-run the application and not rotate again, still works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: did u check the .plist file for orientation properties of the project in iOS5?

Comment: Hi, Where should I look in the plist file? I have set the launch orientations in UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad to include Left and Right Landscape. Nothing else is there. I tried removing them but it didn't change anything.

Comment: wat r u returning in `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` of the rootviewcontroller?

Comment: This is what I am returning.
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape) {
        return YES;
}
    return NO;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is where I went wrong

For iOS 5
when setting the view of the main window of the application, one must use

```
[self.window addSubview: tabBarController.view];
```

Instead of (iOS6 only)

```
[self.window setRootViewController: tabBarController];
```

I am unsure how that changes everything, and the reason it won't work for iOS 5. Nevertheless, it worked.
Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to stick in landscape mode you the blow code, the issue resides in iOS 5, many people face this issue

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    BOOL returningValue=NO;

    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        returningValue=NO;
    }
    else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        returningValue=YES;
    }

    return returningValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sharon, but the issue is not actually with the rotation of the device. It is just the UIViews contained in the window that transform in 90 degrees and change their frame.